# Endpoints in other config file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, endpoint

I have a Web Application and I want to setup my endpoints in other config file (not in Web.config). How to do this? 
I tried set attribute `configSource` in some tags but it doesn't work. 
Structure of Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  //Some configurations
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        //Some bindings
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      //Endpoints
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put your `configSource` attribute on the client element.

Visual Studio will mark it as an error ("The configSource attribute is not allowed."), but it should work anyway.